# File continues to receive infinite data in socket transfer

Tags: c++, sockets

The following code continues to receive data in the same file(**"/tmp/frame"**), 
when the real purpose is to receive in separate files.
It seems that the server starts to receive a file and does not close, continuing to receive data of the following files in the same.

(the comments in the code solve the problem, but delay the transfer of files)

**Sender:**

```
screenshot ptr_screen;
CHAR Block[4096], buffer[512];
int BytesRead, iResult;
for (;;) {
    memset(Block, 0, sizeof(Block));
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    ptr_screen.Start();

    FILE *fp = fopen("screen.jpg", "rb");
    if (!fp) { break; }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int32_t file_size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    iResult = send(socket_, (char*)&file_size, sizeof(file_size), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) { fclose(fp); break; }

    while (file_size > 0) {
        BytesRead = fread(Block, 1, sizeof(Block), fp);
        if (BytesRead <= 0) { break; }

        iResult = send(socket_, Block, BytesRead, 0);
        if (iResult != BytesRead) { break; }

        file_size -= BytesRead;
    }
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    //if (recv_to(socket_, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 5000) <= 0)
        //break;
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
int iResult;
char Block[512];
int32_t file_size;
for(;;) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/frame", "wb");
    if(!fp) { break; }

    memset(Block, 0, sizeof(Block));
    iResult = recv_to((char*)&file_size, sizeof(file_size), 10);
    if(iResult <= 0 ) { break; }

    while(file_size > 0) {
        iResult = recv_to(Block, sizeof(Block), 10);
        if(iResult <= 0) { break; }

        if(fwrite(Block, 1, iResult, fp) != (unsigned)iResult) { return; }
        file_size -= iResult;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system("mv /tmp/frame /tmp/stream.jpg");
    //send(socket_, "OK", strlen("OK"), 0); // response
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TCP is a stream protocol. The receiver wouldn't generally receive data broken down into the same chunks as how the sender sent them - you'll get chunks broken down essentially arbitrarily.

In particular, when the sender sends the last piece of a file, then immediately sends the size and the first chunk from the new file, it's entirely possible that the receiver will receive the last chunk, the size, and the part of the first chunk of next file, all rolled together in one block. `file_size` will go negative, which will get you out of the inner loop this one time. But then, you are going to read into `file_size` some random data from the middle of the next file. It probably just happens to form a very large integer, that's why your inner loop doesn't seem to exit anymore.

In the inner loop read `max(sizeof(Block), file_size)` bytes, so you don't go over the file boundary.

Comment: Can you give me an example for my Linux server?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: how can i change this piece of code recv_to(Block, sizeof(Block), 10);
so that I do not keep having this problem ?

Comment: Which part of `max(sizeof(Block), file_size)` do you find unclear?

Comment: I'm having trouble to compiling using max in this function

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`, then make it [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)

Comment: I've done it, I'm trying this: recv_to(Block, std::max(sizeof(Block), file_size), 10);